# Django sphinx docs made by cookicutter folder confusion

Tags: django, docker, documentation, python-sphinx, cookiecutter-django

I'm a bit confused by the folder structure the sphinx makes for its documentation when starting a fresh new Django project with cookiecutter.
I have my project set up in docker, as per instructions, everything is serving fine and I have the following folder structure for the documentation.

[image: Folder structure created on startup]

When I run the command `make html` in the docs container (or by using the docker-compose local.yml file) I get the following structure.

[image: folder structure after "make html"]

A new folder "html" is created and it's containing everything from the surrounding folders. Is this correct? Am I understanding the process correctly?
For me, it looks like some bad settings for some source folder somewhere.

I'm an experienced python dev, familiar with Docker as well, but I'm pretty new to Django and sphinx.
Can somebody please guide me to the right path, possibly share their Django sphinx docs workflow?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which cookiecutter? I suspect that you changed some parameter for the output or build directory.

Comment: It's a template from pydanny.
That's what I thought as well, but I haven't changed anything. I just changed some docstrings and ran the command to see if it properly refreshes.